# How to handle variable width FieldObjects in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report which is viewed via a CrystalReportViewer control on an .aspx page (using VS2008).

The report has two data-driven FieldObjects (which can contain a variable number of chars) which I would like to display on the same line beside each other.

Problem is when the text in the first FieldObject is too long it overlaps the text in the second FieldObject.

I have tried setting the 'CanGrow=True' and 'MaxNumberOfLines=1' on the first FieldObject to 'push' the second FieldObject further to the right, but this didn't work.

**How do I get the second FieldObject to always display immediately after the first FieldObject regardless of the length of the text in the first?**

Cheers in advance of any knowledge you can drop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a text object to the report. And while editing the text of the text object, drag the field you want to show from the object explorer into the text box. Then hit space, then drag the second field in to the same text box. Your two fields will always be one space a part. You could, of course, add more spaces or any other text you want.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create a function which returns field1 + " " + field2 and add the function to the report.